# Iteratively performing an SQL query on each result of a previous query

Tags: sql

Here is a SQL query to retrieve as all messages of message type 6 for user number 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages
WHERE messageType = '6' AND userId = '1'
```

Let's say I want to write a query like that, but instead of returning just the count for user 1, it returns a table with the count for every user in the table 'users'.

How would I construct something like this? It seems like I'd need to use something akin to a for loop here, but it doesn't look like SQL has anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `group by`:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(*)
FROM messages
WHERE messageType = '6'
GROUP BY userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to print list of all users from 'users' table regardless of there are any relevant message associated to those users exist in 'messages' table.

Below SQL will print list of all users with their respective counts from 'users' and 'messages' table. It will show 'ZERO' as count for users for those who have no relevant messages in 'messages' table.

Assumption - 'Id' column in 'users' table represents userId.

```
SELECT u.id, NVL(COUNT(1),0) as count_of_users
FROM users u left join messages m on u.id = m.userid and m.messageType = '6'
Group by u.id;
```